# Creating named Mutex in c# exe and Accessing it a dll in c++

Tags: c#, visual-c++, mutex

I have two exe's one in C# and other is a vc++ exe . Both of these exe need to access a file.

So I am planning to create a named mutex in c#. vc++ how can i access this named mutex. Can any one give me sample codes for this

Comment: This is probably a good article to start with "An Overview of Managed/Unmanaged Code Interoperability" which you can view at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx

Comment: Just to add to the samples: Don't let the "namespace" bite you. I've had problems with Terminal Services applications before because I didn't expect (and failed to read properly) that the mutex name can contain a scope - for me I needed to replace "MyMutex" with "Global\MyMutex".

Comment: @Benjamin: All (Win2k and later) named objects are now scoped to session or global. And to create a globally named object requires a specific user privilege (normal user accounts cannot do it). This is part of why I avoided the whole ACL question in my answer :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in the C++ code:

```
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, name);
if (hMutex == NULL) {
  // Handle failure.
}
```

If you need to know if the mutex already existed, check for `hMutex != null && GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.

The default ACL you get should be OK for cases with both processes in the same session, otherwise you will need to set an appropriate ACL.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the mutex in c# , Your C++ code would be something like:

```
HANDLE mutexHandle = OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE,0,"NameOfYourMutex");
if(mutexHandle == 0) {
  //handle error
}
```

Comment: thank you thank you thank you!  My mistake was to create the mutex in C# and then call CreateMutex in C++ also.  No error in C++, its just handled as if it was a new mutex - unrelated to the one from C#.  But OpenMutex works!  They use the same mutex.