# Updating progress bar in MFC dialog from .NET C# DLL

Tags: c#, callback, mfc

I have seen this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/318140/How-to-make-a-callback-to-Csharp-from-C-Cplusplus) but I need the reverse and find it confusing.

I have a C# DLL that is performing a lengthy task automating Outlook using interop.

This DLL method is called from my `CDialog` function in MFC.

My dialog has a progress bar control on it. Is it possible to update this progress bar in the dialog from the .NET DLL?

Does my question make sense?

Comment: MFC is exe or dll?

Comment: @santosh MFC is exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Article [Calling an Exported Function in an EXE from Within a DLL](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/dll/article.php/c3649/Calling-an-Exported-Function-in-an-EXE-from-Within-a-DLL.htm) will help you to call exe function from dll only.

However, you can create [named mutex](https://www.google.com/search?q=named%20mutex&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB832GB832&oq=named%20mutex%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6902j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), to sync process or dll progress. named mutex can be accessible from C++ as well as C#. [Creating named Mutex in c# exe and Accessing it a dll in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288654/creating-named-mutex-in-c-sharp-exe-and-accessing-it-a-dll-in-c).

Comment: Thanks. I tried to compile the sample in the first link you provided and it won't compile: `Command line error D8016: '/ZI' and '/Gy-' command-line options are incompatible`. I am compiling in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how one can use a named mutex to do what I want.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle change property setting C/C++ ➔ Code Generation ➔ Enable Function-Level Linking from "No" to "Yes" to solve error mentioned in first comment.

Comment: Ok, I get that to compile. Now I have to see if I can use this in my actual worked scenario where I need to update the progress bar.