# Returning Outlook.Items from DLL to MFC and then iterating the items in MFC

Tags: c#, outlook, mfc, office-interop, items

This is my current function that is part of my C# DLL that uses interop with Outlook:

```cs
public long PurgePTSCalendar(bool bPurgeAll)
{
    long lCount = 0;
    int iLastPercent = 0;

    if (!IsValid())
        return 0;

    try
    {
        // Get the MAPI namespace object (not sure exactly what this is)
        Outlook.NameSpace oMAPI = _OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        if (oMAPI == null)
            return 0;

        // Now get the default Outlook calendar folder
        Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolder = oMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        if (oFolder == null)
            return 0;

        // Ensure it is a calendar folder.  This test is not strictly required.
        if (oFolder.DefaultItemType != Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
            return 0;

        // Get the collect of items from the calendar folder
        Outlook.Items oFolderItems = oFolder.Items;
        if (oFolderItems == null)
            return 0;

        Outlook.Items oItemsToPurge = null;

        // Do we want to purge all entries?
        if (bPurgeAll)
        {
            // Yes, purge all.
            oItemsToPurge = oFolderItems;
        }
        else
        {
            // No, we only want to purge records from today onwards
            // We must get a restricted list
            oFolderItems.Sort("Start");

            // Filter from today onwards (not any start / end 
            // date from a meeting or other item).
            String strStartDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
            string strFilter = "[Start] >=\"" + strStartDate + " 12:00 AM\"";
            oItemsToPurge = oFolderItems.Restrict(strFilter);
        }

        if (oItemsToPurge == null)
            return lCount;

        int iNumItems = oItemsToPurge.Count;

        for (int iItem = iNumItems; iItem >= 1; iItem--)
        {
            object oItem = oItemsToPurge[iItem];
            Outlook.AppointmentItem oEvent = (oItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem);

            int iPercent = ((iNumItems - iItem) + 1) * 100 / iNumItems;
            if (iPercent >= iLastPercent + 5 || iPercent == 100)
            {
                iLastPercent = iPercent;
                // Do Progress
            }

            if (oEvent != null)
            {
                // Get category for this item
                string strCat = oEvent.Categories;

                // Can we delete it?
                if (strCat == "xxx")
                {
                    oEvent.Delete();
                    lCount++;
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oEvent);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oItem);
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oItemsToPurge);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oFolderItems);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oFolder);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oMAPI);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }

    return lCount;
}
```

It is invoked in my MFC executable like this:

```
long COutlookManagerEx::PurgePTSCalendar(bool bPurgeAll)
{
    __int64 lCount = 0;

    if (IsValid())
    {
        VARIANT_BOOL vbPurgeAll = VARIANT_FALSE;
        if (bPurgeAll)
            vbPurgeAll = VARIANT_TRUE;

        throw_if_fail(m_pInterface->PurgePTSCalendar(vbPurgeAll, &lCount));
    }

    return static_cast<long>(lCount);
}
```

It works no problem. It is just that it is lacking **progress monitoring**. I tried to understand (via another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015576/updating-progress-bar-in-mfc-dialog-from-net-c-sharp-dll) I asked) about *updating the progress bar in my `CDialog` from the DLL* but I don't understand the instructions I have read in the links provided in the answer sadly.

As a result I am trying to **simplify** things. It is possible for my DLL to return the `oItemsToPurge` object? And then from MFC we loop this object and perform the deletes from there?

If I could iterate the list from MFC and then make the call to delete as I went I could update my progress bar ...

Comment: Pretty much all automation interfaces are based on COM. Passing COM objects across DLL boundaries is possible (although I don't know what the C# side of things would look like). You could probably simplify your ultimate goal by not using a C# assembly at all, if that is an option. Using a somewhat recent COM library (like [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt)) would turn your C++ COM code into something that's as simple to read and write as C#. And you get deterministic life time as a bonus.

Comment: @IInspectable Does this mean that it is possible for my Visual C++ MFC application **itself** to automate Outlook?

Comment: @IInspectable I also been thinking that it would be easiest if I could pass a callback function to the DLL as a parameter and then the function will just be called. I assume this could work but have not worked out how to do it.

Comment: The Office Automation Interface is based on COM. COM is language agnostic. You can certainly instantiate an Office COM server from an MFC application. You can *probably* also pass some sort of delegate into the C# assembly as a callback. Crossing a runtime boundary is quite involved, though, and the easiest/most reliable approach would be using COM for that as well. It sure looks like you are going to have to use COM, one way or another.